# Changing User Environment with ProcessBuilder + java

Tags: java, environment-variables

I'm trying to change the user of the child process to a user with minor privileges
but when i execute the start method of ProcessBuilder the subprocess exec with the same user of the parent

```
        LinkedList<String> commands = new LinkedList<String>();
        commands.add("vlc");
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
        Map<String,String> enviroment = builder.environment();
        enviroment.clear();            
        enviroment.put("USER", "otheruser");
        enviroment.put("LOGNAME", "otheruser");
        enviroment.put("PWD", "/home/otheruser");
        enviroment.put("HOME", "/home/otheruser");
        enviroment.put("USERNAME", "otheruser");
        enviroment.put("SHELL", "/bin/false");
        builder.directory(new File("/home/otheruser"));            

        Process process = builder.start();
        process.waitFor();
```

I'm working in Linux(Ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

Jim is absolutely right.
But if you still want to run your program as different user you have to user platform dependent tools.

Windows: 
use runas command, e.g.: runas /user:domain\jamesbond regedt32.exe 
Unfortunately runas requires from user to type password manually.
The following article explains how to work around the problem:
http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/WindowsXP/AdminTips/Miscellaneous/RunprogramsasanotheruserinWindows2000WindowsXP.html

Alternatively you can write your own utility in VBS and run it from java. See this post for details: http://weblogs.asp.net/hernandl/archive/2005/12/02/startprocessasuser.aspx

Unix:
see reference of su and sudo. 
su is fine but it requires password too (unless current user is root). 
To work around this you can create expect script (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect).
Expect is installed on most unix distributions by default.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the effective user just by passing in a different `USER` environment variable.  This is a security feature of Linux (and Unix in general), otherwise a malicious user could just set the USER variable to `ROOT`.  Subprocesses always execute as the same user as the parent unless the executable is marked `setuid` or the process does a setuid() to change the effective user (and the setuid() is allowed).